# R markdown having trouble knitting numeric outputs from R chunks

Tags: r, linux, r-markdown

I am using R-markdown on a linux machine for the first time. I am not sure if that has anything to do with the issue but I thought it might be pertinent. I have an R-markdown file with this output selection:

```
---
title: "Homework 1 Econ 6630"
subtitle: "Probability and Statistics"
author: "Dylan Goldvale"
output: pdf_document
---
```

This knitted to pdf fine before I included an R-chunk. Now that I have placed this R-chunk:

````
```{r}
set.seed(49)
dicerollprob=function(x){
  out=data.frame(table(sample(c(1:6),1000000,replace = TRUE)))[x,2]
  return(out/10000)
 }
print(dicerollprob(2)+dicerollprob(4)+dicerollprob(6))
```
````

I receive this error:

> ! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
>   l.103 #
>          # [1] 500841 
>   Error: LaTeX failed to compile Homework-1-Econ-6630.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Homework-1-Econ-6630.log for more info.
>   Execution halted.

I never had an issue with this on my old windows machine. I have the Live Tex distribution as well as `tinytex`. I'm not sure if I have set up my `knitr` package incorrectly (or even my r distribution), or if I have simply neglected something in the latex. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: just a quick gramatical fix in the error line: ! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
l.102 #
       # [1] 50.0841 

Error: LaTeX failed to compile Homework-1-Econ-6630.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Homework-1-Econ-6630.log for more info.
Execution halted

Comment: If there's something to _fix_ in the question, better [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59882687/edit) it rather than making a comment.